# SQLTables return SQL_NO_DATA

Tags: api, odbc

Following code:

```
ret = SQLTables( m_hstmt, (SQLWCHAR *) SQL_ALL_CATALOGS, SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR *) SQL_ALL_SCHEMAS, SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR *) SQL_ALL_TABLE_TYPES, SQL_NTS, L"", SQL_NTS );
if( ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
{
    GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 1 );
    result = 1;
}
else
{
    for( ret = SQLFetch( m_hstmt ); ( ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO ); ret = SQLFetch( m_hstmt ) )
    {
        if( catalog[0].StrLen_or_Ind != SQL_NULL_DATA )
            catalogName = (SQLWCHAR *) catalog[0].TargetValuePtr;
        if( catalog[1].StrLen_or_Ind != SQL_NULL_DATA )
            schemaName = (SQLWCHAR *) catalog[1].TargetValuePtr;
        if( catalog[2].StrLen_or_Ind != SQL_NULL_DATA )
            tableName = (SQLWCHAR *) catalog[2].TargetValuePtr;
    }
}
```

returns SQL_NO_DATA for SQLTables call, whereas following code:

```
ret = SQLTables( m_hstmt, (SQLWCHAR *) SQL_ALL_CATALOGS, SQL_NTS, L"", SQL_NTS, L"", SQL_NTS, L"", SQL_NTS );
if( ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
{
    GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 1 );
    result = 1;
}
else
{
    for( ret = SQLFetch( m_hstmt ); ( ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO ); ret = SQLFetch( m_hstmt ) )
    {
        if( catalog[0].StrLen_or_Ind != SQL_NULL_DATA )
            catalogName = (SQLWCHAR *) catalog[0].TargetValuePtr;
        if( catalog[1].StrLen_or_Ind != SQL_NULL_DATA )
            schemaName = (SQLWCHAR *) catalog[1].TargetValuePtr;
        if( catalog[2].StrLen_or_Ind != SQL_NULL_DATA )
            tableName = (SQLWCHAR *) catalog[2].TargetValuePtr;
    }
}
```

gives me just catalog names and schema/table names are blank.

Does this mean I can't retrieve everything in one shot?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm updating my answer, below you see the old content (starting with the <del>deleted paragraph</del>). As Igor has shown in his answer, it is possible to list everything in one shot.

On the documentation site about the `SQLTables()` is a link to: [Arguments in Catalog Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716447%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There is an explicit entry at the very beginning of the article, stating that calling `SQLTables(hstmt1, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);` will

> [..] return a result set containing information about all tables

There is also a lot of explanations about the influence of the attribute `SQL_ATTR_METADATA_ID` and how the arguments in the catalog functions can be used as

> Catalog function string arguments fall into four different types: ordinary argument (OA), pattern value argument (PV), identifier argument (ID), and value list argument (VL).

I added the link above as a reference.

<del>Yes, I think you cannot list all schemas, all catalogs and all types in one shot. From the documentation at microsoft:</del>

> To support enumeration of catalogs, schemas, and table types, the
>   following special semantics are defined for the CatalogName,
>   SchemaName, TableName, and TableType arguments of SQLTables:
>
> If CatalogName is SQL_ALL_CATALOGS and SchemaName and TableName are empty strings, the result set contains a list of valid catalogs
>   for the data source. (All columns except the TABLE_CAT column contain
>   NULLs.)
>
> If SchemaName is SQL_ALL_SCHEMAS and CatalogName and TableName are empty strings, the result set contains a list of valid schemas for the
>   data source. (All columns except the TABLE_SCHEM column contain
>   NULLs.)
>
> If TableType is SQL_ALL_TABLE_TYPES and CatalogName, SchemaName, and TableName are empty strings, the result set contains a list of
>   valid table types for the data source. (All columns except the
>   TABLE_TYPE column contain NULLs.)

Url: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If I understand this right, you cannot combine this values: Catalogs are only iterated if the CatalogName is `SQL_ALL_CATALOGS` and all other params are empty strings, the same for SchemaName, and so on.

`SQL_ALL_CATALOGS`, `SQL_ALL_SCHEMAS` and `SQL_ALL_TABLE_TYPES` are defined to `%` on my system here.

So, if you query with all three parameters set to the `SQL_ALL_foobar` you will query using `%` as values for all strings, which is not the empty string that is expected for the two other parameters and because of that you will get no result.

Comment: I needed to get the names of all tables for all schemas for all catalogs in the server. Therefore I passed all those constants in. But as you stated this is an improper way of doing it. Please see my solution I just posted as an answer. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently following code works:

```
ret = SQLTables( m_hstmt, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0 );
```

which is kind of weird way to call this function.

Microsoft needs to mention this case somewhere in the documentation, because if the developer sees SQL_ALL_CATALOGS, SQL_ALL_SCHEMAS and SQL_ALL_TABLE_TYPES parameters, (s)he will presume that those values needs to be passed to get all the info from the server.

Solution was found on the easysoft site.

Thank you all for reading.

Comment: Nice! Just curios: Against which database are you running this query and with which odbc driver?

Comment: @erg, SQL Server 2012 Standard(?) with its own driver. I will know better when I get home. But it is weird that MSDN does not cover this case...

Answer (score -2):

The code is wrong because it mixed up TableName and TableType parameters. So you ask for any table in any schema and catalogue but with no type thus you receive empty set because no table in target database has empty type.

This combination is not clearly described in MS documentation so most likely it is driver-specific.